orocommerce - custom OpenID connect login extension
I noticed that oro-commerce support Google and Microsoft SSO. I would like to implement a generico OIDC login extension. I do not seem to find any info in the backend developer guide. Is this possible and can someone provide a link to the documentation / sample to achieve the same?
